# How to add additional parameters to programmatically create buttons?

Tags: java, android

In my program more than 2000 programmatically created buttons. They look like this:

```
//Parameters of buttons
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//Create a button based on...
if (bla-bla)
{   
Button ammian_martsellin_1=new Button(this); ammian_martsellin_1.setText(R.string.ammian_martsellin_1); llPreViewList.addView(ammian_martsellin_1, lParams);
Button ammian_martsellin_2=new Button(this); ammian_martsellin_2.setText(R.string.ammian_martsellin_2); llPreViewList.addView(ammian_martsellin_2, lParams);
}
//And a lot of these groups of buttons.
```

How to add additional parameters to these buttons, such as gravity and text size like "lParams"?

Comment: But I have a lot of buttons, do I will have to all the buttons to append new parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You can look up the methods here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

```
ammian_martsellin_1.setGravity(int)
ammian_martsellin_1.setTextSize(int,float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use setGravity to set the gravity.  Try calling ammian_martsellin_1.setGravity(GRAVITY_VALUE);

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams` is mostly read only, reason being, it's mostly created from an implementation of `AttributeSet` obtained from XML resources.

You'll have to call `setGravity()` on all view objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<ViewGroup.getChildCount();i++){
    if(ViewGroup.getChildAt(i).instanceOf(Button)){
//Do stuff
    }
}
```

Im not sure if the syntax of instanceOf is that exact way, but im sure you will fix it in case it is wrong.